# Remove trailing slash from nginx on HTTP -> HTTPS redirect

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to figure out why the config below redirects, e.g. example.com to https://example.com// (notice the double trailing slash). I've tried using rewrite instead of return a 301 and still the same issue.

My Config:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host/$request_uri;
    }
    server {
            listen       443 default_server ssl;
            server_name  example.com;

            ssl_certificate             /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key         /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;
            ssl_session_timeout         5m;
            ssl_protocols               SSLv3 TLSv1;
            ssl_ciphers                 ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

            location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
                    proxy_read_timeout 10;
                    proxy_pass   http://192.168.1.2:8000;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `$request_uri` already contains the slash (i.e., it's just '/' for the index page) so you might change from this:

```
return 301 https://$host/$request_uri;
```

To this:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```